# Update a multipicklist value on Agreement object based on agreementLineItems field

Tags: apex, trigger, map, before-trigger, cpq

[image]I have two objects. Agreement and AgreementLineItems. It's a masterdetail relationship. One agreement can have multiple items. I have a billing_system__c formula field on agreementLineItem. It's value is either MT or ITC.
Based on the value of billing_system__c in agreementLineItem, I need to update the value of multipicklist (billing_system__c) on Agreement.(The multipicklist value should show ITC and MT both if one agreementline item is MT and another is ITC.

```
trigger SetAgreementFields on Apttus__AgreementLineItem__c(after insert) {
system.debug('@@@@@inside agreement line trigger');
Set<id> agreementID = new Set<id>();
List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> listAgreement = new List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c>();
for(Apttus__AgreementLineItem__c al : Trigger.new)
{
    //    if(al.Apttus__AgreementId__c != null && al.Billing_System__c!=null && al.Billing_System__c!=Trigger.oldMap.get(al.Id).Billing_System__c){
    if(al.Apttus__AgreementId__c != null){    
        agreementID.add(al.Apttus__AgreementId__c);
        system.debug('agreementID'+agreementID);
    }
}
if(agreementID.size()>0){
    List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c > agreementList = [select id, Billing_System__c,(select id,Apttus__AgreementId__c,Billing_System__c from Apttus__AgreementLineItems__r) from Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c where ID IN: agreementID];     
    for(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c a : agreementList){
        for(Apttus__AgreementLineItem__c ali : a.Apttus__AgreementLineItems__r){
            //  Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agg = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();
            if(a.Id == ali.Apttus__AgreementId__c){
                a.Billing_System__c = ali.Billing_System__c;
                listAgreement.add(a);
                system.debug('listAgreement'+listAgreement);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
insert listAgreement;
```

}

The above code works fine, if there is only one agreementlineitem. Otherwise, I am getting the below error
SetAgreementFields: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.ListException: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements Trigger.SetAgreementFields: line 27, column 1

Answer (score 0):

You are making two errors in the code:

1. You have `insert` DML statement whereas you have said in the question that your requirement is to update the Agreement object.
2. In the second `for` Loop you are just adding the same Agreement record multiple times to `listAgreement` which is bound to fail when there is more than one Agreement Line Items.

You should modify the for loops as below:-

```
for(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c a : agreementList){
    a.Billing_System__c  = a.Apttus__AgreementLineItems__r[i].Billing_System__c; 
    String billing = a.Apttus__AgreementLineItems__r[0].Billing_System__c;
    for(i=1;i<a.Apttus__AgreementLineItems__r.size();i++){
        //  Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agg = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();
        if(a.Apttus__AgreementLineItems__r[i].Billing_System__c == billing){
            continue;
        }
        else if(a.Apttus__AgreementLineItems__r[i].Billing_System__c != billing && a.Apttus__AgreementLineItems__r[i].Billing_System__c != null) {
            if(a.Billing_System__c == null || a.Billing_System__c == '') {
                 a.Billing_System__c = a.Apttus__AgreementLineItems__r[i].Billing_System__c;
            }
            else{
                 a.Billing_System__c = a.Billing_System__c +';'+a.Apttus__AgreementLineItems__r[i].Billing_System__c;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    listAgreement.add(a);
}
if(listAgreement.size() > 0 ) {
    update listAgreement;
}
```

Comment: thankyou for pointing that out! i was able to solve